# How to assign object of one class to other in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

how to assign object of interface to a protocol's object?
i've a protocolA and protocolB. all the methods of both the protocols is implemented in MyClass.How to restrict the access to only protocolA's methid and protocolB's methods ?Coding is done in Objective-C for iPhone application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On object creation you can just do this:

```
id <protocolA> protocolAObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Now, unless you use an explicit cast, you can't use protocolB methods.

You can also cast objects of class MyClass to either protocolA or protocolB like this:

```
MyClass *myClassObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
id <protocolB> protocolBObject = (id <protocolB>) myClassObject;
```

Comment: hey... a wrote the your code in MyClass and assigned it to obj of protocolB. but using the object[protocolBobject] of protocolB i'm able to access the methods of other protocols also:(.but that shouldn't be the case right??

Comment: There's no way of blocking the methods completely.  But if you're trying to call protocolA methods, on an object of protocolB, you should get compiler warnings.

Comment: ok... but i'm able to access :(... give me some good links to read about its syntax, or links to example programs

Comment: You might find these two links useful:
http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

Comment: @Tom... In your second comment , you have mentioned that ***"if you're trying to call protocolA methods, on an object of protocolB, you should get compiler warnings"***, i've got a warning for same situation, but how would restrict it to only methods of protocolB???
Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but as far as I know there's no way of completely blocking method access in Objective C.

However compiler warnings are a bad thing, and you should avoid having any in your code.  Compiler warnings should be enough to stop you calling methods that you shouldn't be calling.